# Jmeter repeats request body after fin,ack

Tags: jmeter

I'm trying to use jmeter to make some post requests and I see that after server send [Fin, Ack] and client acked it another POST is send what ends up with RST and error in jmeter, like this:

[image]

I'm using HttpClient4 and have scheduler configured to meet desired request ratio.

Do you know what may be a cause of such behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Response lacked header "Connection: close". After I've added it jmeter started to behave as expected.